# Vue v-for - не понятная ситуация с выводом в console.log

Tags: javascript, vue.js, консоль

В примере ниже осуществляется вывод списка в HTML. Вывод в HTML происходит нормально. Но вывод того же списка в `console.log` дублируется. Почему? Я не смог найти ответа, но заметил следующее:

1. если не выводить в HTML переменную `productsCount`, то дублирования в `console.log` не происходит.
2. если заменить хук `mounted` на `created`, то дублирования в `console.log` также не произойдёт.

Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь сможет объяснить такое поведение.
Vue v2.4.0

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    products: [1, 2, 3],
    productsCount: 0
  },
  methods: {
    cell(product) {
      console.log(product);
      return product;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.productsCount = this.products.length;
  }
}).$mount('#products');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="products">
  <h6>productsCount: {{productsCount}}</h6>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(product, index) in products">
      <span v-html="cell(product)"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Диаграмма-жизненного-цикла](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0)

все дело в том что **mounted** Вызывается сразу после того как экземпляр был смонтирован а в нем вы пытаетесь опять смонтировать.

[created](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created)
[mounted](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted)